# Did Linux have a bug where reading /dev/null would crash the system?

Tags: linux, history

About 10 years ago I've been told by someone that for years Linux used to crash whenever you tried to read `/dev/null` (ie. `cat /dev/null`).

Is this actually true? Did such a bug exist? And if it did, did it exist for years?

---

**Edit**; I found this in Linux 1.0 (March 1994) in `./drivers/char/mem.c`:

```
/*
 * Special lseek() function for /dev/null and /dev/zero.  Most notably, you can fopen()
 * both devices with "a" now.  This was previously impossible.  SRB.
 */
```

Perhaps this is it ...? I didn't investigate/trace all the code..

Comment: I've been using Linux since the late 90s, and have never heard of that bug. Not an answer, because of course Linux existed for at least 7 years before that.

Comment: i once ran into a bug in another *nix system where writing more than some big number of gigabytes to /dev/null would result in an I/O error ... and i hit it in a "normal" use case (not just trying to test for it)

Comment: `/dev/null` is meant to be read. The whole purpose of it is that such a read returns nothing (and writes to it succeed). Its driver is also the easiest possible to write. There can't reasonably have been such a bug.

Comment: Did that someone also ask you to pull their finger or try to sell you a bridge? Reading from `/dev/null` is so common that a bug like this would be discovered and fixed instantly.

Answer (score 2):

`/dev/null` is used by countless scripts, such a bug would have become apparent immediately after a kernel with that bug had booted.

Perhaps it did once happen but I expect it was fixed the same day. I've been using Unix since 1983 (and Linux since 1992) and I've never heard of this.

Comment: I've never seen a script *read* `/dev/null`, it's typically used for *writing* to it.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker, You can read from /dev/null too: `dd if=/dev/null of=MyFile bs=10M count=1`

Comment: @SepahradSalour I know it's *possible*; it's just not as *common* as writing to it, so I would consider it to be at least *possible* that such a bug could, perhaps, have existed for an extended period of time (especially if it was present since the start).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker There are plenty of places where `command </dev/null` is done.

Comment: A common modern use case is `while read something; do ssh remote 'commands ...' </dev/null; done <file` where the `ssh` process would read all the remaining contents from `file` on the first iteration without the redirection. However, this was probably not a widespread problem when `ssh` and Linux were still new.  Anyway, I agree that it is not plausible that such a bug would have existed for any longer time.